# tcpdf position adding white block at bottom of page

Tags: tcpdf

As you can see from this screenshot, there a white area about 100 px tall being added to the bottom of the page that is also pushing the whole page up and off the top of the page. I'm trying to get the text to be on the blue area of the page footer, in white text. I've tried several related suggestions and cant get them to work. Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/lt3J1Wle76Dm

CODE:

```
function downloadFile($rid,$count,$userid,$orderid,$email,$user_password,$owner_password) {
    global $wpdb;

    $rid = intval($rid);
    $query = "
        SELECT 
        filehash,filename,filesize,productid
        FROM {$this->dbtable}_product
        WHERE rid = {$rid}
    ";
    $res = $wpdb->get_results($query);
    $r = $res[0];

    $file_location = $this->getplugindir()."uploads/".$r->filehash.".file";
    if (!file_exists($file_location)) { exit('File does not exist.'); }

    if ($count === true) {
        $res = $wpdb->query("UPDATE {$this->dbtable}_product SET download_count = download_count+1 WHERE rid = {$rid}");
        $this->auditLog($r->productid, $rid, $userid, 'Downloaded');
    }

    $filename = str_replace(' ', '_', $r->filename);

    require_once($this->getplugindir() . 'fpdf/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
    require_once($this->getplugindir() . 'fpdf/tcpdf/tcpdi.php');
    //require_once($this->getplugindir() . 'fpdf/tcpdf/wpds.php');

    if ($orderid === false) { $orderid = '12345'; }

    $pdf = new TCPDI();
    $pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile($file_location);
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false);

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $pagecount; $i++){
        $pdf->addPage();
        $tplidx = $pdf->importPage($i);
        $pdf->useTemplate($tplidx);

        $pdf->SetAlpha(0.5);
        $pdf->SetFont('Courier', 'I', 6);
        $pdf->SetTextColor(255,0,0);
        $pdf->SetXY(5, -5);
        /*
        $pdf->StartTransform();
        $pdf->Rotate(5);
        */
        $pdf->Write(0, "This guide individually licensed to $email ($orderid)");
        /*
        $pdf->Rotate(0);
        $pdf->StopTransform();
        */
        $pdf->SetAlpha(1);
    }

    $pdf->SetProtection(array(
        'modify','copy','annot-forms','fill-forms','extract','assemble'
    ),$user_password,$owner_password,3);
    $pdf->Output($filename,'D');

    exit();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To move your text, change his position with [`setXY()`](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a00ec13928f57b17c21040acc881fe482)

Replace :

```
$pdf->SetXY(5, -5);
```

By :

```
$pdf->SetXY(5, -100); // change Y value to be on blue area
```